# Python subprocess.check_call of the bash script is not waiting for subprocesses to finish

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

```
N = 50000
with open('input', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(N):
        f.write(str(i) + '\n')

run_command = '/bin/bash -e -o pipefail -c "((sort | tee >/dev/null >(cat | (tee >/dev/null >(sort >&3)))) <input 3>output)& wait"'

subprocess.check_call(run_command, shell=True)

time.sleep(sleep_time)

print sh.wc("output", "-l")
```

Running this python piece of code with `sleep_time = 0` returns 0, but with `sleep_time = 1` returns 50000.

The reason seems to be in not waiting for bash subprocesses to finish. Probably, my usage of  the `wait` function is not correct. I made experiments, but no satisfactory solution found.

Comment: Not sure it will help your problem directly, but you should be able to reduce the complexity of this operation by either running without `shell=True` or by running with `executable='/bin/bash'`.  Right now, you're launching `sh` only to turn around and launch `bash` without ever actually using the `sh` shell for anything.

Comment: Experiments hint at subschells run by parenthesis are not waited by bash. As far as I understand, subshell jobs are not visible to parent process, so there are not standard commands to wait for them.

Comment: Have you considered trying to do this in native Python instead of spawning a shell command?  Might be easier to deal with that way...

Comment: there are some couple of things that i didnt get from your code: why are you writing in a file `f` opened for reading? what is `sh.wc`? what is your bash script doing? subprocess.check_call(...) is to start your process and wait it to finish its execution

Comment: There is a misprint. The file "input" is supposed to be opened in "w" mode. sh is a module from python-sh library, it implements wrapper over most shell commands, so sh.wc is an analogue of shell `wc` command. subprocess.check_call waits for the shell command to complete, but not for its child processes.

Answer (score 1):

When you `/bin/bash` your command is going to run in a subshell, so you are immediately exiting the process. Also the command you are running in that subshell is running in the background, because of the `&` at the end, you can pass `$!` as parameters to `wait` for it to *wait* until the last background process exits.